# (regex) retrieve whole phrase with specific word between 2 symbols

Tags: regex, perl, match

My question looks like some other questions in Stackoverflow, but i did not find exacly what I was looking for.

I need to retrive a whole phrase that contains a specific word. This phrase is also between ">" and "<".

For example:

```
text:
 "<div>bla bla bla</div><div>blu blu GOLD blu</div><form> bla bla...."

What I need is:
 blu blu GOLD blu
```

I'm trying to do that in Perl. What I have until now is:

```
$specific_word = GOLD;
while ($var=~/[>]?(?<phrase>(.*?)\Q$specific_word\E(.*?))</ig) {
   script.....
}
```

What I get with this regex, given the example above, is:
  `<div>bla bla bla</div><div>blu blu GOLD blu`

How do I do to find the first ">" before my specific word, and not the first ">" of the entire text?

Comment: Don't parse html with regexp, use dedicated libs

Comment: I thought that Perl is used for such things...! lol. Now I'm confused.

Comment: Extract the text of divs, then match those against the work you're looking for.

Comment: Interesting idea, Ikegami!

Comment: DMurta you are correct that Perl is great for regex, however using regex to parse html is generally not great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML::TreeBuilder is a better way to parse HTML in Perl.

But to answer the question, you probably want to match `/[^>]*${specific_word}[^<]*/g`, which basically says that `>` is not on the left hand side and `<` is not on the right hand side of the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

An html parser's been rightly mentioned.  You can find "GOLD" in the second `div` of your string by using [Mojo::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/~tempire/Mojolicious-3.11/lib/Mojo/DOM.pm) in the following way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = '<div>bla bla bla</div><div>blu blu GOLD blu</div>';
my $dom  = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

for my $e ( $dom->div->each ) {
    print $e->text if $e->text =~ /\bGOLD\b/;
}
```

Output:

```
blu blu GOLD blu
```